# Implement a dynamic selectbox in html

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to develop a select box so that I can change the selected option dynamically

e.g.

```
selectbox option              display message
---------------------------------------------
field 1                       text
field 2                       integer
field 3                       bool
```

There are three select boxes. The first select box provide three options.

1. when select box 1 is selected, the other select boxes will have only 2 options (excluding the selected one)
2. When select box 2 is selected,  the other select boxes will have only 1 option (excluding the selected two)
3. When a select box's value changes, the appropriate message is displayed.

All of the text that will be displayed is read in from a database as an array in the following format:

```
name text
id   integer
address text
```

Then I create a select box with the three option
When I set select box 1's value as `name`, the text message is displayed, and so on.

How should I implement this? (I hope you get my idea) Thank you again for your help.

Thank you

Comment: please feel free to ask question, i may not explain the question clearly

Answer (score 10):

I'd suggest something akin to the following:

```
var sel1 = document.getElementById('one'),
    sel2 = document.getElementById('two'),
    sel3 = document.getElementById('three'),
    sels = document.getElementsByTagName('select'),
    reset = document.getElementById('reset');

function disableOpts(elem) {
    for (var i = 0, len = sels.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (sels[i] != elem) {
            var opts = sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option');
            for (var c = 0, leng = opts.length; c < leng; c++) {
                if (c == elem.selectedIndex) {
                    opts[c].disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

sel1.onchange = function() {
    disableOpts(this);
};

sel2.onchange = function() {
    disableOpts(this);
};

sel3.onchange = function() {
    disableOpts(this);
};​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/M33N9/).

---

**Edited** to add the messages, as requested in comments (which I overlooked in the actual question...):

```
var sel1 = document.getElementById('one'),
    sel2 = document.getElementById('two'),
    sel3 = document.getElementById('three'),
    sels = document.getElementsByTagName('select'),
    reset = document.getElementById('reset'),
    msgs = ['text','integer','boolean'];

function disableOpts(elem) {
    for (var i = 0, len = sels.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (sels[i] != elem) {
            var opts = sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option');
            for (var c = 0, leng = opts.length; c < leng; c++) {
                if (c == elem.selectedIndex) {
                    opts[c].disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    hideMessage(elem);
};

function displayMessage(elem){
    for (var i=0,len=sels.length;i<len;i++){
        if (sels[i] == elem){
            var span = elem.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
            span.innerHTML = msgs[i];
            span.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
};

function hideMessage(elem){
    for (var i=0,len=sels.length;i<len;i++){
        if (sels[i] == elem){
            var span = elem.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
            span.innerHTML = '';
            span.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
};

sel1.onchange = function() {
    disableOpts(this);
};

sel2.onchange = function() {
    disableOpts(this);
};

sel3.onchange = function() {
    disableOpts(this);
};

sel1.onfocus = function() {
    displayMessage(this);
};

sel2.onfocus = function() {
    displayMessage(this);
};

sel3.onfocus = function() {
    displayMessage(this);
};

sel1.onblur = function() {
    hideMessage(this);

sel2.onblur = function() {
    hideMessage(this);
};};

sel3.onblur = function() {
    hideMessage(this);
};​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/M33N9/2/).

Comment: That is great, very close to answer ,would you mind teach me how to  a display a message for each select box as well?

Comment: What message in response to what events, and based on what data..?

Comment: sorry i just back , for opition 1: the message is text, for opition 2: the message is int, for opition 3: the message is text

Comment: actually the message is retrieve from database, i can handle that part and a 3 variable / array of message will be obtained

Comment: ...I'm beginning to remember why I normally prefer jQuery, now... =/ But I think that this should work. The `reset` button is not particularly well placed, but I figure I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader to solve, according to personal taste.

Comment: Thank you You are very very nice person as i have work on it long time but does not figure it out

Comment: actually i do not have to so advance i just need a "text" string on the screen when the select box is selected, for example, when user selected "opition 1" , then a "text" will display beside the select box

Comment: Base on the example one and print out a string if a select box is selected will be perfect. I would like achieve is to only print out a variable beside select box .will it takes time? anyway, you work a lot and i will attempt it by myself

Comment: I don't understand; do you want the message to *stay* there, and remain visible, once an option's been selected?

Comment: Yes. you get it. stay there and remain visible. first it is not there, when the option box select, the message display,  Only when the select box option change again , it change to another message, thanks

Comment: I really need to you to add this to your question: and explain very, very carefully what should happen. And when. In response to what. Will the messages always be in the same order? What defines whether it's the `text`, `integer` or `boolean` message? What's it meant to represent?

Comment: I have edit it, actually, the message just a string, has no meaning

Comment: it depend on the select box value , not necessarily same order

Comment: too much code... too many functions that make the same things... just with a massive refactoring could be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/), maybe it can help you.

For the data than you can put a `php foreach` for the `<option>` element on the `select`.

Comment: thank you . let me have a trail and post some simple code here if it not work